# What is the difference between these two function prologue instruction sequences?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

the test is on `32-bit x86`. I compiled the code with `gcc 4.2`, optimization level `o2`. I compiled the C code into binary, and then use `objdump` to disassemble it.

Here are two sequences of instructions used for the function prologue:

```
0804a6f0 <quotearg_n>:
804a6f0:       8b 44 24 04             mov    0x4(%esp),%eax
804a6f4:       b9 ff ff ff ff          mov    $0xffffffff,%ecx
804a6f9:       8b 54 24 08             mov    0x8(%esp),%edx
804a6fd:       c7 44 24 04 40 e1 04    movl   $0x804e140,0x4(%esp)
804a704:       08 
804a705:       e9 c6 fa ff ff          jmp    804a1d0 <quotearg_n_options>
804a70a:       8d b6 00 00 00 00       lea    0x0(%esi),%esi


0804a730 <quotearg>:
804a730:       83 ec 1c                sub    $0x1c,%esp
804a733:       8b 44 24 20             mov    0x20(%esp),%eax
804a737:       c7 04 24 00 00 00 00    movl   $0x0,(%esp)
804a73e:       89 44 24 04             mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
804a742:       e8 a9 ff ff ff          call   804a6f0 <quotearg_n>
804a747:       83 c4 1c                add    $0x1c,%esp
804a74a:       c3                      ret
804a74b:       90                      nop
804a74c:       8d 74 26 00             lea    0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
```

Note that in function `quotearg`, register `esp` is decreased with `0x1c` before it is used to access the stack and get some arguments. Accutually according to my experience, I think the `sub` then `access` pattern is quite common for instructions compiled with `O2`.

However, note that in function `quotearg_n`, register `esp` is directly added with `0x4` to access the stack. (I think the meaning of instruction at address `0x804a6f0` is to put the return address of call site to register `eax`, am I right..?) According to my observation, the pattern used by the first function is rare, around 5% for `gcc` compiled middle size C program with `O2`.

So here is my question:

Why does compiler generate function prologue instructions in a way similar to `quoterag_n`? What is the exact meaning of the first three instructions start from address `0x804a6f0`?

Why doesn't compiler always generate function prologue instructions following the `sub` then `access` pattern? (such as `quoterag`)

Am I clear? thanks a lot

Comment: Might be useful to show the code that generated this or a reference to the code for `quotearg_n_options` (could have been the GNUlib portability library or a number of equivalent ones). Knowing how these functions were defined would allow us to tell exactly what it is doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one with `sub %esp` is the typical make-some-room-on-the-stack, then put args there, then call a function.  You also do this to reserve space to spill local vars from registers to memory.

The first one is tail-call optimized to just jump to `quotearg_n_options` after loading some values into registers.  The args to the final call are the same args that were on the stack when we entered `quotearg_n`.

It can get away with this because it doesn't need any stack space for local variables.

I'm not sure what exactly it's doing to `4(%esp)`.  I think that's where one of the args lives, because it's setting it to a constant.  IIRC, `(%esp)` is the return address, and `4(%esp)` is the first arg.  It's setting the first arg to a constant, probably the address of a buffer.  I'm not clear on why it might be doing some of the other things, unless it's jumping into the middle of `quotearg_n_options`, where the value in `%edx` might matter.  (and would explain why it's loading other args from the stack into registers that callees can clobber.

Comment: This was probably gcc targeting the win32 `__vectorcall` ABI, where the first two args go in `ecx` and `edx`.